# spark udf - classcastexception with json

Tags: java, json, apache-spark, user-defined-functions, classcastexception

I am running java spark code reading some json data and converting one of the fields to uppercase through UDF
The code works fine when running in local mode but when running in cluster (under kubernetes)  I get a ClassCastException like this:

```
UDF1 uppercase = new UdfUppercase() ; 
session.udf().register("uppercasefunction",uppercase , DataTypes.StringType) ; 

StructField[] structFields = new StructField[]{ 
        new StructField("intColumn", DataTypes.IntegerType, true, Metadata.empty()), 
        new StructField("stringColumn", DataTypes.StringType, true, Metadata.empty()) 
}; 
StructType structType = new StructType(structFields); 

List<String> jsonData = ImmutableList.of( 
        "{\"intColumn\":1,\"stringColumn\":\"Miami\"}"); 

Dataset<String> anotherPeopleDataset = session.createDataset(jsonData, Encoders.STRING()); 
Dataset<Row> anotherPeople = session.read().schema(structType).json(anotherPeopleDataset);            
anotherPeople.show(false); 

Dataset<Row> dfupercase = anotherPeople.select(callUDF("uppercasefunction", col("stringColumn"))); 
dfupercase.show(false);
```

```
Caused by: java.lang.ClassCastException: cannot assign instance of scala.collection.immutable.List$SerializationProxy to field org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.org$apache$spark$rdd$RDD$$dependencies_ of type scala.collection.Seq in instance of org.apache.spark.rdd.MapPartitionsRDD
    at java.io.ObjectStreamClass$FieldReflector.setObjFieldValues(ObjectStreamClass.java:2287)
    at java.io.ObjectStreamClass.setObjFieldValues(ObjectStreamClass.java:1417)
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.defaultReadFields(ObjectInputStream.java:2293)
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readSerialData(ObjectInputStream.java:2211)
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readOrdinaryObject(ObjectInputStream.java:2069)
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readObject0(ObjectInputStream.java:1573)
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.defaultReadFields(ObjectInputStream.java:2287)
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readSerialData(ObjectInputStream.java:2211)
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readOrdinaryObject(ObjectInputStream.java:2069)
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readObject0(ObjectInputStream.java:1573)
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readObject(ObjectInputStream.java:431)
    at scala.collection.immutable.List$SerializationProxy.readObject(List.scala:490)
    at sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor9.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at java.io.ObjectStreamClass.invokeReadObject(ObjectStreamClass.java:1170)
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readSerialData(ObjectInputStream.java:2178)
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readOrdinaryObject(ObjectInputStream.java:2069)
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readObject0(ObjectInputStream.java:1573)
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.defaultReadFields(ObjectInputStream.java:2287)
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readSerialData(ObjectInputStream.java:2211)
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readOrdinaryObject(ObjectInputStream.java:2069)
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readObject0(ObjectInputStream.java:1573)
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.defaultReadFields(ObjectInputStream.java:2287)
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readSerialData(ObjectInputStream.java:2211)
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readOrdinaryObject(ObjectInputStream.java:2069)
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readObject0(ObjectInputStream.java:1573)
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readObject(ObjectInputStream.java:431)
    at org.apache.spark.serializer.JavaDeserializationStream.readObject(JavaSerializer.scala:75)
    at org.apache.spark.serializer.JavaSerializerInstance.deserialize(JavaSerializer.scala:114)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.ResultTask.runTask(ResultTask.scala:83)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.Task.run(Task.scala:121)
    at org.apache.spark.executor.Executor$TaskRunner$$anonfun$10.apply(Executor.scala:402)
    at org.apache.spark.util.Utils$.tryWithSafeFinally(Utils.scala:1360)
    at org.apache.spark.executor.Executor$TaskRunner.run(Executor.scala:408)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
```

Any help will be appreciated

Answer (score 1):

Problem is solved now it was related to some jar conflict with spring boot
The classcastexception is misleading cause we get the impression that somehow our dataframe does not get well serialized (difference between local and cluster) while in fact it has nothing to do with the code istelf but the jar conflicts